# Notification action button text is always all caps on Android Pie

Tags: notifications

Notification actions on Android pie are all caps instead of sentence case. Is there a way to change it programmatically?
This is how I create the notification.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = getActivityReplyPendingIntent(pushMessage, showMuteActionAsMute, personEndpoints);
Action replyAction = new Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_reply_16,
            getString(R.string.notification_reply_action), pendingIntent);

builder.addAction(replyAction);
```

with above code, I get the action button text with sentence case but on Pie it is somehow all caps.
Any ideas?